# Pass Vector2 to Instantiated GameObject

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to get an AI sprite to randomly shoot a SINGLE bullet while walking around. This is a 2D Top-down perspective. The sprite can move up, down, left and right. It randomly changes directions.

When I call the `ShootBullet()` function, the bullet just sits at were it is instantiated.

[image]

The Sprite has a ***WalkingController*** attached to it that calls a bullet prefab. The bullet prefab has a script that just handles the movement.

How do I get the bullet to know which direction it should travel when it is created?

I am trying to AVOID the use of the `FindObjectWithTag` methods. As I have been learning, it seems that - that specific tag is slow.

I really appreciate any help while I am learning!

**WALKING SCRIPT**
This script is also generic so I could attach different enemies with the same setup.

```
public class WalkingController : MonoBehaviour {


    public Animator    anim;
    public Rigidbody2D body;
    public float moveSpeed  = 0.75f; //HOW FAST THE ENEMY WALKS


    //DEALS WITH SHOOTING BULLET 
    public GameObject   objectToSpawn; //WHICH BULLET TO SHOOT
    public float        shootDamage     = 1.0f;
    public float        timeToSpawn     = 1.0f;
    private float       internalTimer   = 2.0f;

    //Holds the direction the enemy should move
    public Vector2 enemyMovement;


    void Awake() {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        body = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine ("ChangeDirection");
    }

    void Update() {

        //WHEN TO SHOOT A BULLET
        this.internalTimer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (this.internalTimer > this.timeToSpawn) {
            this.ShootBullet();
            this.internalTimer = 0.0f;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        //THIS MOVES THE ENEMY
        body.MovePosition (body.position + enemyMovement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void ShootBullet() {
        //THIS FIRES THE BULLET
        Instantiate(objectToSpawn, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        //HOW DO I MAKE THE BULLET MOVE?????
         gameObject.Direction(enemyDirection);

        //HOW DO I PASS HOW MUCH DAMAGE BULLET HAS??

    }


    public Vector2 getEnemyMovement() {
        //TRIED MAKING A PUBLIC ACCESSOR FOR THE BULLET TO ACCESS, BUT DIDN'T WORK
        return enemyMovement;
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeDirection() {
        //RANDOMLY CHANGE THE ENEMY DIRECTION
        while(true){
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range (0.3f, 1.5f));
            randomDirection();
        }
    }

    void randomDirection() {
        switch(Random.Range (0,3)){
            case 0:
                //Debug.Log ("Moving enemy Up");
                 enemyMovement = new Vector2 (0,1);
                break;
            case 1:
                //Debug.Log ("Moving enemy Right");
                 enemyMovement = new Vector2 (1,0);
                break;
            case 2: 
                //Debug.Log ("Moving enemy Down");
                 enemyMovement = new Vector2 (0,-1);
                break;
            case 3:
                //Debug.Log ("Moving enemy Left");
                 enemyMovement = new Vector2 (-1,0);
                break;
            default:
                 enemyMovement = new Vector2 (0,0);
                break;
        }
        anim.SetBool ("Walking", true);
        DefineFacingDirection (enemyMovement);

    }

    void DefineFacingDirection (Vector2 vec){
        //THIS IS FOR THE ANIMATOR TO PLAY THE CORRECT ANIMATION
        anim.SetFloat ("InputX", vec.x);
        anim.SetFloat ("InputY", vec.y);
    }
}
```

**PROJECTILE SCRIPT**
I wanted this script to be pretty generic, so I could attached any animation or prefab to it so i could have different bullets. ie rocks, arrows, throwing stars etc...

```
public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour {

    public float        moveSpeed = 4.0f;

    //Tried to make the direction public so we could set it on creation, didn't work.
    public Vector2  Direction { get; set; }

    private Rigidbody2D body;

    void Awake() {
        body = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){

        body.MovePosition (transform.position + Direction * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

UPDATE
I tried just making the bullet move by placing it on the scene. Using the below code. It doesn't move when I add `body.MovePosition (transform.position + transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);` but if I remove transform.forward the bullet moves to the center of the screen. There are no other scripts attached to the bullet.

[image]

```
public float     moveSpeed = 4.0f;
    public Rigidbody2D body;

    void FixedUpdate(){
        body.MovePosition (transform.position * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: So you want straight movement or something like projectile?

Comment: @HamzaHasan yes, see the update question.

Comment: I answered the question "How do I get the bullet to know which direction it should travel when it is created?" But are you now asking a new question on how to actually move a bullet, rather than setting the Direction property of an Instantiated GameObject with the Projectile Component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things you are using in wrong way. Basically it is just the matter of concept.

- `Instantiate` will give you an `Object` in return. So whatever you want to do with instantiated object, you have to keep reference of that.
- `gameObject.Direction`, actually `gameObject` always represents the `GameObject` on which that very script is attached.

So what you have to do is simply

- `Instantiate` your bullet
- Keep reference of that `Object`
- Get the script attached to your bullet prefab

Change your `ShootBullet` method as,

```
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(objectToSpawn, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        bullet.GetComponent<Projectile>()._direction = enemyDirection;
```

Now on other hand, your `Projectile` script should look like,

```
public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour {

    public float _moveSpeed = 4.0f;

    public Vector2  _direction = Vector2.zero;

    private Rigidbody2D _body;

    void Awake() {
        _body = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        _body.position = _body.position + _direction.normalized * _moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```

Now it should work if you provide proper direction.

Comment: I think I started crying. THANK YOU! You have been so helpful! This worked!

Answer (score 0):

They have an example of this in the [Unity API docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) actually.

```
 Rigidbody clone;
 clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
 clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * 10);
```

Instantiate returns an Object reference then you can cast to the desired type using the as statement. In your case you would just do `as GameObject`, then call `GetComponent<Projectile>().Direction = enemyDirection;` on the returned and casted GameObject variable.

Comment: It's 2D bro, Vector3.forawrd is not gonna be work probably

Comment: Yes... that is the code from the API. If you read on further, you will see that I call the GetComponent for the actual MonoBehavior he wants to add his Direction Vector... The answer is not always the code in the box to be copied and pasted. Also answer was posted before his update.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just instantiate the projectile as a Projectile? You would then eliminate the call to GetComponent.

Comment: I agree with @MikeHunt; however, the current implementation for the code has a prefab GameObject for the Projectile. I was answering based on his current code.

Comment: @Mike Hunt, actually it is not projectile but only class name :) otherwise he did want to move object in straight line.

Comment: Ok I understand Martin :). @HamzaHasan I do not understand what you're trying to say lol. Yes it is a class name and you can instantiate the object as a Projectile as long as you cast it to Projectile. "Projectile projectile = Instantiate (projectilePrefab, position, rotation) **as Projectile**;" then you can access everything you need with that variable. "projectile.Direction = Vector3.up" etc...

Comment: @MikeHunt Man.. Leave.. He got his relevant answer.. That's enough :P :D